# Laravel Pivot Tables - accessing from inverse relation-table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

UPDATE: Apparently `$problem->userRatings()->count();` returns 1, so a record does exist, but the script still doesn't enter the foreach loop for some reason...

UPDATE 2/Solution: I feel incredibly foolish, but the reason it isn't working, is that I was calling `foreach($problem->userRatings() as $rating){` when it should be `foreach($problem->userRatings as $rating){` (dynamic property)

---

In my database I have problem_ratings, problems, and users. I have models for users and problems, and problems_ratings is a pivot table between problems and users with an extra 'content' column that stores the numeric rating value (1-5).

The many-to-many relation in my Problem model:

```
public function userRatings(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'problem_ratings', 'author_id', 'problem_id')->withPivot('content');
}
```

The many-to-many relation in my User model:

```
public function problemRatings(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Problem', 'problem_ratings', 'author_id', 'problem_id')->withPivot('content');
}
```

When creating a problem_ratings element, I attach it to my user model like so:

```
$user->problemRatings()->attach($problem->id, array('content' => $val));
```

I can access the pivot table through the user, but when I try this:

```
foreach($problem->userRatings() as $rating){
    echo "In average loop";
    $newAverage = ($rating->pivot->content) + $newAverage;
}
```

it doesn't find any records, even though some exist in the database. Am I using these relations correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So if you do `dd($problem->userRatings())` you're getting an empty collection?

Comment: Actually no, it returns an extremely long laravel object. One of the problems i'm having debugging is that I am calling the function through an ajax call. Would it help to see the object? Or what else can I look at?

Comment: It wouldn't really help to see the object because it's a `Illuminate\Support\Collection` and I'm trying to asses if you're getting an empty list or not, so try `dd($problem->userRatings)` or `dd($problem->userRatings()->get())`.

Comment: As a side note, you can output debug data directly in your browsers's developer tools using **[FirePHP](https://github.com/plus3interactive/laravel4-firephp)** (you'll find browser extensions for both Chrome and Firefox that work with it). It's great for dumping data without messing up the normal response.

Comment: all of those return a `Illuminate\Support\Collection`... I'll check out FirePHP, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a foreach loop over something like this, you need to use dynamic properties (ie. without parentheses):

`foreach($problem->userRatings as $rating){` instead of `foreach($problem->userRatings() as $rating){`

Answer (score 0):

In the Problem model I think your relationship should looks something like :

```
public function userRatings(){
return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'problem_ratings', 'problem_id', 'author_id')->withPivot('content');
```

}

Comment: Unfortunately I had tried that, but it didn't change anything, so I changed it back... But thank you for the suggestion